# Running tess-two on phone

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

I have downloaded the [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) then I have imported all from that location to my project. Compile *.so files and try to run this on my phone like that:

```
    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
    baseApi.end();
```

but result is sad:

```
02-06 15:43:32.095    4072-4072/my.package.name E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.package.name, PID: 4072
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: my.package.name.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit:()V
        at my.package.name.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit(Native Method)
        at my.package.name.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:46)
        at my.package.name.activities.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:214)
        at my.package.name.activities.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:138)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5441)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3400)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you fixed the problem? I have the same issue... It's impossible to solve....

Comment: @Aspicas yes, I make wrong package

Comment: I have `*.so libraries` on folder `src/main/jniLibs` how to implement that on project? can you help me please? Always it reports the same error....

Comment: rename Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClassInit to Java_my_package_name_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClassInit

Comment: okay, but... where i can find `Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClassInit`?

Comment: Oh my god.... I LOVE YOU MAN!! I fixed it change package name....

Comment: @Aspicas glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello  I think you don't have compiled *.so files matching all cpu.

Please edit Application.mk as follow

APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips arm64-v8a x86_64 mips64
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang

Then compile that Best Regards